# Passing Core Data attributes from viewController to another viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I'm a complete beginner in iOS and Core Data. I've followed Lynda.com's Core Data example and am still trying to grasp the gist of everything.

My current build has a UITableViewController (Let's call it resultsTVC) that passes the selected objectAtIndex to a UIViewController (displayUserVC). I was wondering is there a possibility to pass the details already loaded from the UIViewController (displayUserVC) to another UIViewController (addMoviesVC)?

Basically - do you have to save the current fetched items in that UIViewController (displayUserVC) somewhere, or is there a possibility to access what is already loaded in the UIViewController (displayUserVC) to the new UIViewController (addMoviesVC)?

Thanks Guys

Comment: If your transition is via `UIStoryboard` segue you can use the `prepareForSegue` method and pass your `displayUserVC` variable/s to public variable/s in the `addMoviesVC` via the segue's destination view controller property.

Comment: Forgive me for being rather naive but what exactly do you pass? I'm under the assumption you have to pass the current managedObjectContext onwards?

Comment: For this answer, he is saying to pass the object directly. Once you read the object from CoreData, it's in your memory so you can pass it as long as you have a reference to me

Comment: so this object is still in memory and can be passed onwards. I'm sorry if this is very blunt but what object is it that I pass on to the segue? - is it NSFetchRequest or the NSManagedObject?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I've seen it done and recommend is to create a Singleton `ManagedObjectContext` that is accessible from multiple VCs. Then in your `prepareForSegue` you pass in the object identifier to the next VC. That VC on load can then get a reference to your context and load anything you need for it. This allows your VC to already have the `MOC` in case you need to do any changes to it (i.e. editing/deleting/inserting into CoreData).

Comment: Can this singleton class handle multiple entities and relationships? I have about 4 of them. Sorry if that's a silly question - still a beginner on core data.

Comment: The point of the singleton is to create one instance that is used across the whole app - this ensures that you don't have multiple instances of a MOC throughout the app and worry about your data having to sync between them. The singleton class isn't a new object - it simply returns the same MOC to any VC that is trying to access it. To your question: Yes. It's working on an enterprise app with 3+ MB in the coreData DB and around 14 entities with ~60 total relationships.

Comment: Just wondering - is the AppDelegate technically a singleton when you check "use core data"? Essentially can you import AppDelegate into every class to get those core data objects?

Comment: Technically you can put it on the AppDelegate and instantiate it in `AppDidFinishLaunching`. Then return the object anytime someone wants to access it. Another approach is if you want to create a CoreData class that you can import into every class, take a look at this article for how to implement a singleton. Notice the dispatch_once that you would wrap around your `MOC` initialization code that ensures you only have one instance of the `MOC` that you're passing out to every class trying to grab it. http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Ah ok - then this is similar to what Tim Roadley does in his latest Core Data book. Think i'll need to go back to the drawing board. Thanks for your help.